# MYSQL error 1064 ,how to fix it?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and have a sql error. I need to have distinct columns for datetime and for every distinct datetime, I want to show the max impact_id

select max(impact_id),distinct datetim 
from news
 where impact_id is not null and 
datetim is not null
group by datetim 
order by datetim asc

I am getting error

```
 SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct datetim from news where impact_id is not null and
```

datetim is not null'

```
    CREATE TABLE `news` (
    `datetim` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `symbol` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `impact` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `_id` MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `impact_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3072
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select distinct max(impact_id),datetim 
from news 
where impact_id is not null and datetim is not null
group by datetim 
order by datetim asc`